# Transform letters in a string

Tags: python, python-3.x, programming-challenge

I am learning python and want to improve my skills in it. So could someone advice of how to improve the code below (this is a simple programming problem taken from one of the web sites). I feel like my code is not really Pythonic.

**Problem:** Using the Python language, have the function `LetterChanges(str)` take the `str` parameter being passed and modify it using the following algorithm. Replace every letter in the string with the letter following it in the alphabet (ie. c becomes d, z becomes a). Then capitalize every vowel in this new string (a, e, i, o, u) and finally return this modified string.

```
from sets import Set

def LetterChanges(str): 
   vowels = Set(['a', 'e', 'i', 'o', 'u'])
   new_str = ''
   for i in str:
      cur_char = i.lower()
      if cur_char == 'z':
         new_str += 'A'
      elif ord(cur_char) >= 97 and ord(cur_char) < 122:
         new_char = chr(ord(i) + 1)
         new_str += (new_char if new_char not in vowels else new_char.upper())
      else:
         new_str += i
   return new_str

if __name__=='__main__': 
   print(LetterChanges(raw_input()))
```

Comment: Why two Python versions?

Comment: sorry, my bad. I will edit it now.

Comment: Welcome to codereview.SE! Your code does not seem to run on any version of Python 3 because the sets module is removed (it is deprecated since Python 2.6 https://docs.python.org/2/library/sets.html )

Comment: @Josay I'd say he wanted python-2.x tag.

Comment: I wanted to use python3.6. Made corresponding changes.

Comment: Please do not update the code in your question to incorporate feedback from answers, doing so goes against the Question + Answer style of Code Review. This is not a forum where you should keep the most updated version in your question. Please see *[what you may and may not do after receiving answers](//codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1765)*.

Comment: Welcome to Code Review! It is preferred if you wait at least 24 hours after you ask your question, and even after receiving an answer, before accepting an answer to give everyone a chance. You might decide you like another answer even more!

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Your code defines a function with a clear input and a clear output. Also, you've put the call to it behind the `if __name__ == '__main__':`. You've taken good habits on this points. Nonetheless, a few things can still be improved.

**Python version**

If you are learning Python, there is no good reason to start with Python 2 which is reaching its end of life. You should focus on learning Python 3, going to be supported for a while and with various warts corrected (and obviously more features).

In any case, the [`sets`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/sets.html) module is not required since Python 2.6 since we have the [`set` builtin](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#set).

**Style**

There is an official standard Python style guide called [PEP 8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/). This is highly recommended reading. It gives guidelines to help writing code that is both readable and consistent. The Python community tries to follow these guidelines, more or less strictly (a key aspect of PEP 8 is that it provides guidelines and not strict rules to follow blindly).

It deals with various aspects of the code style: naming conventions, indentation convention, etc.

You'll find various tools to try to check whether your code is PEP 8 compliant and if is it not, to try and fix this:

- [`pycodestyle` package](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pycodestyle) (formerly known as `pep8`) to check you code
- [`pep8online`](http://pep8online.com/) to check your code with an online tool
- [`autopep8` package](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/autopep8) to fix your code automatically
- Also, this is also checked by various linters: [`pylint`](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/pylint), [`pyflakes`](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/pyflakes), [`flake8`](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/flake8), etc.

In your case, the major points I would fix are:

- indentation should be 4 space
- function names should `snake_cased`
- you could try to take into account the advice to use `join` instead of "CPython's efficient implementation of in-place string concatenation".

**Naming**

On top of the snake-case point mentioned above, a few things could be improved in the naming. Naming is a difficult part of programming so what I suggest are just personal, far from perfect, suggestions (from a non-native English speaker). In your case, I'd call the function `tranform_string` so that it conveys the fact that:

- it is an action (a noun would correspond to an object/class name)
- it applies to string (and not to single character even if the distinction is fuzzy in Python compared to other programming languages)

The name `str` is a bit of a problem because it hides the [`str` builtin](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#str). I do not find any alternative better than `str_` which is still pretty poor :-(.

*Edit: I don't know why I didn't think about "s" in the first place but after reading it in another answer, it looks like a much better option indeed. I am too lazy to edit my code everywhere.*

Finally, `i` is a good name for an (integer) index. For a single character, `c` seems easier to understand (`char` if you feel verbose).

**Chained comparison**

In Python, you can [chain comparison](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/expressions.html#comparisons). If your case, you can write:

```
elif 97 <= ord(cur_char) < 122:
```

**More beautiful character check**

From [the Zen of Python](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0020/):

> Beautiful is better than ugly.
>   Explicit is better than implicit.
>   Simple is better than complex.

In your case, you could avoid the call the `ord` and get rid of the magic number by writing the simple:

```
elif 'a' <= cur_char < 'z':
```

**Rewriting the logic**

You could have the logic adding a character to `new_str` in a single place.

```
    cur_char = c.lower()
    if cur_char == 'z':
        new_char = 'A'
    elif 'a' <= cur_char < 'z':
        new_char = chr(ord(c) + 1)
        if new_char in vowels:
            new_char = new_char.upper()
    else:
        new_char = c
    new_str += new_char
```

Then, you could try to makes the logic as close as possible to the way it is given in the problem for instance by making "z" a special case only for the operation where you take the following letter.

```
    low_char = c.lower()
    if 'a' <= low_char <= 'z':
        new_char = 'a' if low_char == 'z' else chr(ord(c) + 1)
        if new_char in vowels:
            new_char = new_char.upper()
    else:
        new_char = c
    new_str += new_char
```

**Shorter way to define `vowels`**

Because strings are iterable and `set` takes any kind of iterable, you could write:

```
vowels = set('aeiou')
```

**Better ascii check**

You could reuse values from the [`string` module](https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html) to make your test more beautiful:

```
   if low_char in string.ascii_lowercase:
```

**Removing string concatenation**

As mentionned earlier, it is advised not to use string concatenation and use `join` instead, when relevant.

At this stage, the code (with added tests) looks like:

```
import string

def transform_string(s):
    vowels = set('aeiou')
    lst = []
    for c in s:
        if c in string.ascii_letters:
            new_c = 'a' if c.lower() == 'z' else chr(ord(c) + 1)
            if new_c in vowels:
                new_c = new_c.upper()
        else:
            new_c = c
        lst.append(new_c)
    return "".join(lst)

if __name__=='__main__':
    assert transform_string("")            == ""
    assert transform_string("qwertyuiop")  == "rxfsUzvjpq"
    assert transform_string("asdfghjkl")   == "btEghIklm"
    assert transform_string("zxcvbnm")     == "AydwcOn"
    assert transform_string("1234567890")  == "1234567890"
    assert transform_string("QWERTYUIOP")  == "RXFSUZVJPQ"
    assert transform_string("ASDFGHJKL")   == "BTEGHIKLM"
    assert transform_string("ZXCVBNM")     == "AYDWCON"
    assert transform_string("(){}<>+_-=")  == "(){}<>+_-="
```

Comment: I was under the impression that uppercase letter shouldn't be transformed.

Comment: `set(['a', 'e', 'i', 'o', 'u'])` could be replaced with `{'a', 'e', 'i', 'o', 'u'}`

Comment: @CristianCiupitu Indeed, this is a nice suggestion. I went for a different option at the end because it is shorter but both look fine to me. As for the uppercase, I went overboard thinking I had tested everything which is apparently not the case, I hope most comments apply anyway...

Comment: Why not use `string` instead of `str`?

Comment: @SolomonUcko because there's a [`string`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/string.html) module.

Comment: @SolomonUcko It's an acceptable option but then it would hide the `string` module when imported. I guess "s" is a very good name in that context...

Comment: @Josay, speaking of tests, I took some of yours and included in [my answer](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/189434/1208) as [doctests](https://docs.python.org/3/library/doctest.html).

Comment: Good point. I normally use `from string import ascii_letters`, etc.

Comment: `s`, `str` and `string` are all perfectly fine names here. Don’t be afraid of name hiding (*especially* not locally within a function!), that’s what qualified names are there to solve. The underscore in `str_` is completely spurious and unnecessary.

Comment: @EricDuminil thought I had tested for all letters uppercase and lowercase but I was wrong. For now, I'll just leave things as is...

Comment: @EricDuminil I've updated my answer.

Answer (score 13):

Instead of having those `if`s you could use a translation table to speed things up (see [`str.maketrans`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.maketrans) and [`str.translate`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.translate)).

```
import string

def _build_translation_table():
    ascii_vowels = 'aeiou'
    d = {c: chr(ord(c)+1) for c in string.ascii_lowercase}
    d['z'] = 'a'             # z is a special case
    for k, v in d.items():   # and so are vowels
        if v in ascii_vowels:
            d[k] = v.upper()
    return str.maketrans(d)

_TABLE = _build_translation_table()

def LetterChanges(s):
    """Change letters in string s using a special algorithm.

    Replace every letter in the string with the letter following it in the
    alphabet (ie. c becomes d, z becomes a) ...

    >>> LetterChanges('qwertyuiop')
    'rxfsUzvjpq'
    >>> LetterChanges('1234567890')
    '1234567890'
    >>> LetterChanges('zxcvbnm')
    'AydwcOn'
    """

    return s.translate(_TABLE)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    import doctest
    doctest.testmod()
```

I took the liberty to rename the parameter `str` to `s` for reasons already mentioned by others. `_build_translation_table` and `_TABLE` start with an underscore because it doesn't make much sense for them to be "public".

I also took some tests from [Josay's answer](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/189433/1208) and put them into the documentation string of the function, so that the [`doctest`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/doctest.html) module can run them.

```
# python3 letterchanges.py -v
Trying:
    LetterChanges('qwertyuiop')
Expecting:
    'rxfsUzvjpq'
ok
Trying:
    LetterChanges('1234567890')
Expecting:
    '1234567890'
ok
```

Comment: Excellent answer with a much different approach. Nice to be able to see the bigger picture instead of focusing on details!

Answer (score 7):

Believing the `Python-3.x` tag, here's a way to rewrite your method:

```
def letter_changes(text):
    vowels = set('aeiou')
    new_str = ''
    for c in text:
        cur_char = c.lower()
        if cur_char == 'z':
            new_str += 'A'
        elif ord(cur_char) >= 97 and ord(cur_char) < 122:
            new_char = chr(ord(c) + 1)
            new_str += new_char.upper() if new_char in vowels else new_char
        else:
            new_str += i 
    return new_str

if __name__ == '__main__':
    print(letter_changes(input()))
```

With those modifications:

- `snake_case` method name
- `set` for Python3
- 4 spaces indent
- reversed logic for `upper` if the letter is a vowel.

Another alternative would be to work with generators and join the letters at the end instead of building a new string character by character.

Answer (score 5):

Here are some improvements that I'd make (supposing that your code is using Python 2.x):

- I'd indent the code so that it'll be a multiple of four
- There's no reason to make the vowels a `Set()`. A string should work just fine as strings are iterable in python
- rename the `str` argument to something else as that's a builtin keyword in python
- I'd simplify the chained comparison: `ord(cur_char) >= 97 and ord(cur_char) < 122` to `97 <= ord(cur_char) < 122`

That being said you'd have so far:

```
def LetterChanges(str_):
    vowels = 'aeiou'
    new_str = ''
    for i in str_:
        cur_char = i.lower()
        if cur_char == 'z':
            new_str += 'A'
        elif 97 <= ord(cur_char) < 122:
            new_char = chr(ord(i) + 1)
            new_str += (new_char if new_char not in vowels else new_char.upper())
        else:
            new_str += i
    return new_str


if __name__ == '__main__':
    print(LetterChanges(raw_input()))
```

Answer (score 0):

There are some excellent pointers and implementations already, here are a few more.

1. If you can implement your algorithm in an idiomatic fashion without extraneous imports, then do so. creating a `set` of the vowels is great however, the same effect can be achieved with data structures that are lighter weight.
   `Strings` and `tuples` and tuples are lighter and have the added benefits of being immutable. For this application, a string of vowels will suffice.
2. As Cristian Ciupitu pointed out, a having a direct transformation is great for this problem as it avoids unnecessary computations. Rather than using the string library, the same can be achieved using a plain 'ol `dict`
3. Rather than building up a string using the `+` operator, we can do better (speed, memory utilisation and portability across python implementations) with the `"".join` method.
4. The function `letter_changes` seems to do a lot, it'd be better to approach it in a modular fashion i.e. build simpler functions to abstract away the different tasks

**The setup: building the shift map**

```
letters = tuple(map(chr, range(97, 97+26)))  # tuple of lowercase letters
vowels = "aeiou"
letters_right_shifted = letters[1:] + (letters[0],) # tuple (z, a, b, ..., y)
dest = tuple(c.upper() if c in vowels else c for c in letters_right_shifted)
shift_map = dict(zip(letters, dest))
```

**The workhorse: change a single letter**

```
def change_letter(some_character):
    """(chr) -> chr
    Return a single character shifted (and capitalised) appropriately
    according to the problem statement

    All characters are first converted to lower case.

    >>> change_letter('a')
    'b'
    >>> change_letter('d')
    'E'
    """
    return shift_map[char.lower()]
```

**The Full function: handling strings**

```
def letter_changes(some_string):
    """(str)->str
    Return a new string with every letter shifted (and capitalised) according to the problem statement.

    All characters are first converted to lower case.
    >>> letter_changes('done')
    'EpOf'
    """
    return "".join(map(change_letter, some_string))
```

The higher order function `map` applies the function `change_letter` to every element in `some_string`. The same effect can be achieved with the comprehension
`"".join((change_letter(c) for c in some_string))`.

Now to extend the function to handle strings with non letter elements e.g. (1, 2, ?, .,  /) one only has to modify the `change_letter` function.

Comment: The point of a set is that it's fast to check `c in vowels`. To be fair, there won't be much difference between `O(1)` and `O(n)` with `n = 5`.

Answer (score 0):

I notice that there are a lot of answers that compare each letter to its ASCII value.  This isn't bad, per se, but we can use the `string` module (which contains a full list of ASCII letters) to our advantage:

```
import string
ordered_letters = string.ascii_lowercase * 2 + string.ascii_uppercase * 2
```

Do you see what I did there?  By putting the ordered strings in twice, I automatically handle the wrapping from Z/z to A/a.

Here's my full code:

```
import string
ordered_letters = string.ascii_lowercase * 2 + string.ascii_uppercase * 2


def change_letters(s):
    result = []  # will be returned as a joined-string

    # Loop through each character, transforming them as necessary,
    # and add them to the result list:
    for c in s:
        # Do the rotation, if necessary:
        i = ordered_letters.find(c)
        if i >= 0:
            c = ordered_letters[i+1]
        # Convert vowels to uppercase:
        if c in 'aeiou':
            c = c.upper()
        # Store the character in the result to be returned:
        result.append(c)

    # Return the result as a join()ed string:
    result ''.join(result)
```

Using the `ordered_letters` approach may seem strange, but it provides a convenient way to "rotate" letters by an arbitrary amount.  For example, if you change:

```
c = ordered_letters[i+1]
```

to:

```
c = ordered_letters[i+13]
```

you will have modified the code to be a ROT13 encoder/decoder!  And if you want to go backwards one step, you can add **25** instead of **1**.  (Or you could subtract **1**, provided that you change `str.find` to `str.rfind`.)

Comment: You don't need both to be doubled; instead, just having `string.ascii_lowercase + 'a'` would work, and then do something like `for c in s.lower()` (because the OP lowercases every character first).

Comment: @Dannnno, you're correct in that I don't need both to be doubled in this case -- but I did that to accommodate arbitrary rotations (such as by 2, 13, and 25).  That way, you don't have to worry about adding 'a', or 'abc', or 'abcdef...'; it's the same no matter how much you rotate (provided that 0 <= amount <= 26, of course!).

Comment: Even then, you at most only need the lower case due to the casing requirements. Furthermore, it isn't at all obvious that the OP wants or needs arbitrary rotations. As-is it takes a little bit to realize why you're doing what you're doing; at least factoring it out into a function, something like `rotate_letter(char, n)` would be cleaner.

Comment: @Dannnno, I'm pretty sure you're correct about the casing requirements; the reason I kept uppercase as uppercase is because of Josay's example, and the fact that the original poster didn't specify in the problem that vowels should always be lowercase (I know the original poster's code contradicts this, but I decided to follow the requirements in the problem statement instead).